# Error (1,0) while updating

Tags: android, sdk, updates, build.gradle

First I was getting error

> config.ini is malform . Try recreating it.

I search on stackoverflow . One solution which i get is **update the android studio**. 
I go to the link android studio is showing. download the zip file from the website (in different folder from previous android studio folder).

Now when i open the android studio(from recently updated folder) . I am receiving the error

> Error(1,0) Plugin is too old please update to more recent version

I have updated my sdk and all the suggestion sdk sugggested but i still got the same error

**My build.gradle(Project:xyz)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

My **Build.grade(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.talha.test_fragement"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

}
```

Please suggest what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0
```

Use stable and avoid using alpha version.

Comment: Thanks ,this error goes away but a new comes :( . Now all the java class giving error on getActivity()

Comment: Replace getActivity() with "this"

Comment: Got error on findviewbyId as well.I am new to android studio. So couldn;t know much about

Comment: I guess i should quit android studio and run again or Refresh the android studio